# PHP - Parsing strings

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract data from anchor urls of a webpage i.e. :

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com');
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
{
    $href= $element->href;
    $name=$surname=$id=0;


    parse_str($href);
    echo $name;
}
```

Now, the problem with this is that it doesn't work for some reason. All urls are in the following form:

```
name=James&surname=Smith&id=2311245
```

Now, the strange thing is, if i execute

```
echo $href;
```

I get the desired output. However, that string won't parse for some reason and also has a length of 43 accroding to strlen() function. If , however, i pass `'name=James&surname=Smith&id=2311245'` as parse_srt() function argument, it works just fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have any example input HTML we can test on?  In addition, can you elaborate on "I get the desired output"?  Lastly, for safety's sake, never execute `parse_str` without [the second parameter](http://us1.php.net/parse_str).  It's risky to blindly overwrite global variables.

Comment: `$name=$surname=$id=0;` ... ?

Comment: `parse_str($href, $out); var_dump($out);` what do you see?

Comment: what the hell is this line doing? $name=$surname=$id=0;

Comment: @KyleK Assigning `0` to `$name`, `$surname` and `$id`, what do you think it's doing?

Comment: @KyleK appears to be initializeing those variables with a value of `0`. Probably OP is used to another language that doesnt like surprise variables!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm gonna take a guess that your target page is actually one of the rare pages that correctly encodes `&` in its links. Example:

```
<a href="somepage.php?name=James&amp;surname=Smith&amp;id=3211245">
```

To parse this string, you first need to unescape the `&amp;`s. You can do this with a simple `str_replace` if you like.

Comment: That wouldn't explain why `echo $href;` allegedly gives the correct output.  (Unless OP was mistaken or was viewing the output in a web browser.)

Comment: @Mr.Llama Your parenthetical "unless" is exactly it ;) Notice the `strlen` output OP gave?

Comment: Hah! I totally missed that bit.

Comment: When you spend too long on StackOverflow, you start being able to see these "invisible" errors ;)

Comment: Oh, yes, that explains it xD Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the links are absolute, you just need the query string. You can use `parse_url` and use an out parameter with parse_str access an array;

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com');
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
{
    $href= $element->href;


    $url_components = parse_url($href);
    parse_str($url_components['query'], $out);

    var_dump($out)
}
```